# Remote Debugging Azure Web App Terminates After Page Load

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to remotely debug a web app on azure. I published using Web Deploy the debug configuration, and added the breakpoint, right clicked on the Attach Debugger on my Web App instance and the debugger launched and everything is looking good.

But after waiting for like 20sec for the page to load( the debugger launched my website), the visual studio debugger terminates and im being returned to normal editing, and the web page actually load on the browser. Have no clue what that might be happening.

Comment: By any chance are you using an Express edition of Visual Studio?  According to the documentation here Remote Debugging is not supported in Express editions. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug

Comment: nop, Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, web api url is carbonplayground.azurewebsites.net, i made sure the name does not have - dashes as i read in another post at StackOverflow it might cause issues

Comment: Create a new MVC app, deploy and try debugging that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you enable Remote Debugging for the right Visual Studio version in your web app configuration?